# What is the best term for a list of options or choices?

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns

I just looked up "list" and I got "a number of connected items".

Is there a more specific term to use when those items are options or choices?

Comment: Your own plural terms *options* and *choices* work: "*Here are your options/choices: (list of items)*".

Comment: Can you provide a sentence?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In computing a list is typically referred to as a collection. Specifically a collection of items. Items can be of many different forms such as a whole row of information, or a more complex object.

Depending upon context however queue is a nice word representing a first in first out type of scenario. There's also the word column which is typically a list of autonomous singular data elements, such as name, state, or zip code.

Cavalcade is also rather lovely but I doubt that's what you're after. List is also a very valid word in the english language and there is a List class in the Java programming language. The plural form of the word option is also good. The HTML element is referred to as a select list. An array is the basic practical form.

Answer (score 1):

The term that springs to mind is *menu*.  It is, for example, the standard term for the drop-down lists of options used on computer interfaces.

Comment: Add supporting evidence, and I'll probably upvote this.

Answer (score 1):

You could say 'a selection'.

As in 'a selection of chocolates' or 'a selection of dishes' or 'a selection of options'.

It means 'a range of choices' - like a menu or list.